# Set drush alias for current path

Tags: drush

Is it possible to associate a path with a specific drush alias?

Use case:

I'm on my local dev machine and I'm in /var/www/site1 when I run drush I want it to run as drush @site1 without me having to append @site1 every time.

My alias files are all stored in the my local home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store settings.php in the default folder, then Drush will already behave as you desire.  If settings.php is in some other folder (e.g. 'site1'), see the site-set command (`drush help site-set`)